# Bitcoin and ArchLinux on a Pogoplug

Tags: network, linux

I'm interested in using a pogoplug to run bitcoin. From my understanding, I should be able to connect to the pogoplug from another device (RasPi with AM BEs) and mine on my own. I'm having trouble figuring out what I'm doing wrong -- I've got bitcoin cloned to the plug from github, but in following what it seems others have done,

```
make -f makefile.unix USE_PNP=-USE_IPV6=0
```

nets

```
make: *** No rule to make target `makefile.unix'.  Stop.
```

Suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Bitcoin now (as of a few hours ago) uses autotools to generate makefiles. You'll need to run `./autogen.sh` first, then `./configure`, then `make`.

Comment: Already ran those scripts.

Comment: Then you should just need to run `make`. See [build-unix.md](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/master/doc/build-unix.md).

Answer (score 0):

bitcoin moved to autotools a little while back. Provided you have all of the dependencies installed and in their normal places, you should be able to just do:

```
./autogen.sh
./configure
make
```

See [doc/build-unix.md](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/master/doc/build-unix.md) for instructions.